# How to prevent the object from becoming null?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have the following code. During page load, I get the customer object from the database. After that when I try to access the same object in a different method, the object comes out as empty. Assume Student object has properties like firstName, lastName etc.

```
Public class Test

    Public oStudent as Student

    Public Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        oStudent = getStudent(22) 'This is just a sample. This is not my actual database.

    End Sub

    Public Sub Update(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as System.EventArgs) Handles crtlStudent.Update
        Update(oStudent)'This one updates makes a database call to update the studnet

    End Sub
End class
```

When the page loads, the student is returned from the database correctly. However, when I'm on my update method, oStudent object becomes null/empty. Is this the way the page life cycle works? If yes, I would need to store the oStudent in a session or cache it right? Is there any other way to prevent the oStudent from becoming null other using session variables or caching it?

Comment: Web is stateless. Do some research on the topic, this has been discussed way too many times for my taste already... You may consider switching to MVC, just for the sake of understanding what actually happens.

Comment: In cases like these I just 'cheat' and use a hidden element in the form to hold the value, that way it's maintained in the viewstate during postback. Variables always lose their values after postback finishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the case that the object is `null` in the other method but after the page is disposed. That happens at the end of every page's lifecycle, so when it was rendered as HTML and sent to the client.

So you either have to re-initialize/load the object on every postback or persist it somewhere. In your sample-code you are loading it always in `Page_Load`, hence i doubt that it's `null` anywhere. So i guess that it's not the real code which could be:

```
Public Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
      oStudent = getStudent(22) ' in a button-click handler it will be null since it's a PostBack
    End If
End Sub
```

> Is there any other way to prevent the oStudent from becoming null
>   other using session variables or caching it?

[Nine Options for Managing Persistent User State in Your ASP.NET Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx)